# Booking Disney World in Orlando tickets online

Tags: usa, online-resources, disney, orlando

I am from Buenos Aires Argentina and I am planning my next vacation to Disney World Orlando.

I am trying to do my hotel reservation and buy my tickets for the parks.

I have a Disney account in the official website and now I realized that in the bottom part of the web, I can choose the country where I am.

I am from Argentina and when I choose this country, I go to the website for doing a reservation hotel and the website tell me that I need to call a phone for doing that (the reservation).

If I choose United State (English) in the website, I go to the website for doing my reservation and I have a calendar and I can directly buy.

So my question is, can I put United States (English) in the website and buy from Argentina without problem?

So I want to know if it's the same, if that part of the page only changes my language or my purchase?

Comment: @Traveller I have to buy from Argentina. They have different ways to buy tickets and doing the reservation depending the country from which I am buying

Comment: You should post an answer (possibly with a bit more detail) to help others who may have the same question in future

Comment: user92038 are you please able to post an answer?

Answer (score 1):

On calling Disney World they told OP that he has to use the site for his country, as they need different details and do bookings different depending on where the guests live.